# List RemoveAll with another method call

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

So, I am trying to loop through a list and remove the items from the list and and Destroy the GameObject, so at first I did this:

**Pooler.Remove()**

```
protected static void Remove(GameObject obj){
    PoolerItem p = (
        from item in pool
        where obj == item.gameObject
        select item
    ).FirstOrDefault();

    pool.Remove(p);
    GameObject.Destroy(p.gameObject);
}
```

**Loop Through a list**

```
foreach(PoolerItem p in pool.Where(x => x.poolName == "cube")){
    if(totalItems > minPoolSize && p.inactiveLifeSpan > 0 && !p.gameObject.activeSelf && Time.time - p.disableTime >= p.inactiveLifeSpan){
        Pooler.Remove(p);
    }
}
```

I get an error that basically says **You can delete items from the list you are looping over**

Okay, makes sense. So I looked around and saw that I should use `RemoveAll` so I created the code for that and replaced it with my foreach like this:

```
pool.RemoveAll(
    p => p.poolName == entry.poolGroupName 
    && p.inactiveLifeSpan > 0 
    && !p.gameObject.activeSelf 
    && Time.time - p.disableTime >= p.inactiveLifeSpan
);
```

The only thing that is missing is this line `GameObject.Destroy(p.gameObject);` from `Pooler.Remove`. How can I implement that with `pool.RemoveAll()`?

Comment: How about calling  **GameObject.Destroy(p.gameObject);  ** inside  dispose method of **PoolerItem** object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a statement lambda instead of expression, and you can do whatever you want inside it:

```
pool.RemoveAll(
p => { 
        if(p.poolName == entry.poolGroupName && 
           p.inactiveLifeSpan > 0 && 
           !p.gameObject.activeSelf  &&
           Time.time - p.disableTime >= p.inactiveLifeSpan)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(p.gameObject);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
     });
```